# How to build an audio mute button?

Tags: arduino, audio, relay, opto-isolator, stereo

I'm planning on building a mute button that would physically cut the audio signal from or to my computer. This could be used for both input and output. I would like to be able to disconnect my microphone or my speakers by the press of a button.

I was thinking about using an arduino or simply an attiny85 chip for the logic part (using a button as an input and triggering the pass/block part).
The reason I want to use a MCU is to be able to report the state with a LED, pass HID events via USB to the OS and trigger with things other than a button.

The only thing that I don't know how to do is how to disconnect both stereo channels.
My guess was that I would need a mechanical relay or an opto-isolator but there might be a better way to do this.

The ideal solution would physically break the connection and wouldn't induce distortion when the signal is allowed to pass.

Do you have any idea about the optimal way to proceede?

Comment: Explain why you think that a microcontroller is needed. Why a relay? Why an opto-isolator ? Why **not** a simple DPDT switch: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Double-pole-double-throw-switch-DPDT#:~:text=A%20Double%20Pole%20Double%20Throw,switch%20a%20very%20versatile%20switch. ? Also better explain your setup (make a drawing).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I edited my question. I'd like to use inputs nicer than a DPDT switch, like a simple switch or even a capacitive touch. I'll also probably report events via USB.

Comment: Audio can be switched with analog muxes or analog switches, but it does not support speaker level currents, depending on switch used the headphone level currents may be achievable. Line and mic level certainly doable.

Comment: Then I suggest that you use a relay as it is the easiest to "get right" (I mean: working). Other solutions are possible (analog mux/switch of line level audio) but require **experience** to get right. A relay is much more user friendly.

Comment: There's also dedicated audio muting ICs, but interfacing these will be harder to get right (meaning: working) than a relay